# React Native WebView handling android hardware button

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I have an app (Webview exactly) and I'm trying to handle the Android hardware button to return from the second page for example to the first one. My problem now is the button won't close the app anymore, and I don't know what should I do. Here is my code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
    this.state={

     };

this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.handleBackButtonClick);
}
componentWillUnmount() {    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

onNavigationStateChange(navState){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(navState));
  canGoBack = navState.url == initialUrl && !navState.loading
}


handleBackButtonClick() {
     this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].goBack();
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `handleBackButtonClick` determines whether the app is to be kept running or not.

Currently, you are always returning `true`. Instead, you could check whether the current navigation state is such that you would like to close the app, and return `false` accordingly.

```
handleBackButtonClick() {
    const canGoBack = someCalculation();
    if(canGoBack)
        this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].goBack();
    }
    return canGoBack;
}
```